# Stack Copy Constructor using array

Tags: c++

I have a copy constructor that isn't working right. I believe my logic is wrong but I dont know where and why. My code and my output is down below.

Member Functions:

```
    Stack300::Stack300(): MAX_STACK(3)
{
    stackArray = new(std::nothrow) Element300[MAX_STACK];
    if(stackArray == NULL)
    {
        cerr << "There is not enough memory for this stack. This stack will not be implemented correctly." << endl;
    }
    else
    {
    top = -1;
    }
}

Stack300::Stack300(const int size):MAX_STACK(size)
{
    stackArray = new Element300[MAX_STACK];
    top = -1;
}

Stack300::Stack300(Stack300& old):MAX_STACK(old.MAX_STACK)
{
    Stack300 tempStack;
    stackArray = new (std::nothrow)Element300[old.MAX_STACK];
    top = -1;
    Element300 temp;
    while(!old.isEmpty()){
        temp = old.pop300();
        tempStack.push300(temp);
    }

    while(!tempStack.isEmpty()){
        temp = tempStack.pop300();
        push300(temp); 
        old.push300(temp); 
    }
}
Stack300::~Stack300()
{
    Element300 tempValue;

    while(!isEmpty())
    {
        tempValue = pop300();
    }

    if(isEmpty())
    {
        delete [] stackArray;
    }
}

void Stack300::push300(const Element300 number)
{
    if(isFull())
    {
        cerr << "The stack is full." << endl << "The push was unsuccessful" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        top++;
        stackArray[top] = number;
    }
    return;
}
Element300 Stack300::pop300()
{
    Element300 number = 0.0;

    if(isEmpty())
    {
        cerr << "The stack is empty" << endl << "The pop was unsuccessful" << endl;
        return 0.0;
    }
    else
    {
        number = stackArray[top];
        top--;
        return number;
    }
}

void Stack300::viewTB300()
{
    Stack300 tempStack(MAX_STACK);
    Element300 tempValue;

    while(!isEmpty())
    {
        tempValue = pop300();
        tempStack.push300(tempValue);
        cout << tempValue << endl;
    }
    while(!tempStack.isEmpty())
    {
        tempValue = tempStack.pop300();
        push300(tempValue);
    }

    return;
}

void Stack300::viewBT300()
{
    Stack300 tempStack(MAX_STACK);
    Element300 tempValue;

    while(!isEmpty())
    {
        tempValue = pop300();
        tempStack.push300(tempValue);
    }
    while(!tempStack.isEmpty())
    {
        tempValue = tempStack.pop300();
        cout << tempValue << endl;
        push300(tempValue);
    }

    return;

}

bool Stack300::isFull()
{
    bool status;

    if(top == MAX_STACK - 1)
        {
            status = true;
        }
    else
    {
        status = false;
    }

    return status;
}

bool Stack300::isEmpty()
{
    bool status;

    if(top == - 1)
    {
        status = true;
    }
    else
    {
        status = false;
    }

    return status;
}
```

My driver:

```
    using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    Stack300 stack1(6);
    stack1.push300(100);
    stack1.push300(200);
    stack1.push300(300);
    stack1.push300(400);
    stack1.push300(500);
    stack1.push300(600);


    Stack300 stack6(stack1);
    stack6.viewTB300();

    return 0;
}
```

My current output:

```
    The stack is full.
The push was unsuccessful
The stack is full.
The push was unsuccessful
The stack is full.
The push was unsuccessful
600
500
400
```

Please let me know if I need anything else to this post so that it can help you answer this question.

Thanks!

Comment: You should learn to use a debugger. Or just debug with by printing out in the appropriate places.

Comment: If you make the copy constructor's parameter `const`, as it should be, the compiler will find a bug for you.

Answer (score 1):

Your default constructor constructs a stack with maximum size 3. You then try to put 6 elements in it:

```
Element300 temp; // MAX_STACK == 3

while(!old.isEmpty()){  // But old has 6 elements
    temp = old.pop300();
    tempStack.push300(temp);
}
```

Also, your copy constructor empties the object been copied from. Those are very confusing "copy" semantics.

You should simply copy the data of one stack to the other, without popping or pushing. This could be trivially done if you use `std::vector<Element300>` for storage instead of your own dynamically allocated array. In this case, the default copy constructor would do the job.